# Dynamically clone LinearLayout and its contents in the same parent layout

Tags: android

How can I grab an element and clone it in the same view multiple times programmatically?
I have this `LinearLayout` inside a `RelativeLayout` and I want to clone that `LinearLayout` that I have previously written in the xml file, about 10 times in the `RelativeLayout`.

This is the structure:
[image]

This is the code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_android"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="62dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:src="@drawable/cartuxa_logo"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/menu_btn"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_icon" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout_ID"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/relativeLayout">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:id="@+id/ll_preview_ID"
            android:background="#ff393939"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ll_image_ID"
            android:background="#ff767676"
            android:contentDescription="@string/dfg" />


    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to make a separate layout XML file for the one you want keep adding in relativelayout. 
Once you do this you can add the layout in this manner

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext() .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 RelativeLayout main =(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1); 

for(int i=0;i<9;i++){ 
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sub_layout, null);
 main.addView(view);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse you can right click your layout and use the option **Extract Include**. (You can also do it manually.) It will extract your layout into a separate XML and it will make you able to include your newly created layout once more using `<include layout="@layout/yourlayout"/>`.